# NSUserDefaults won't save my high score permanently

Tags: ios, swift

my NSUserDefaults doesn't save my game high score properly. When am playing(testing) the game it works ok but when i quit(terminate) and restart or when i transition from scene to scene my high score goes back to 0. can anyone help me fix this issue? thank in advance.

```
var score = 6
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")
//Check if score is higher than NSUserDefaults stored value and change           NSUserDefaults stored value if it's true

if score > NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore") {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(score, forKey: "highscore")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")
```

Comment: Try to Make var score : Int = 6  and set value in user default as value for key and just do println for this to check value

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a problem with your use of NSUserDefaults here. Are you sure that you are setting the highscore value to score as expected? This code snippet doesn't really show anywhere that the highscore value is being used.

Comment: thanks guys. i just needed to assign highScore to the saved value. your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that this statement, which appears twice, does nothing at all:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")
```

It fetches the `"highscore"` key's value from user defaults, but immediately *throws it away*, because you are not assigning the result to anything, like this:

```
let highscore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")
```

Thus, even though you are successfully *storing* the high score in user defaults, you are never *retrieving* it - so there is no basis for your claim that it is not being saved, because you have given yourself no way of *knowing* whether or not is has been saved.

Comment: works great now, you are a genius @matt. just one of the silly mistakes beginners like myself do sometimes. thanks a lot

Comment: I actually discuss this matter in my Swift intro: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_function_parameters_and_return_value Notice at the end of that section I talk about failure to capture the result returned from a function...